# Making a program that implements functions that work with arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string

Doing an assignment where I have to implement some functions. One of those functions is to check if a string is a palindrome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char string[] = "cameron";
char string2[] = "mah";
char palindrome[] = "madam";
char notPalindrome[] = "music";

int removeChar(char *str1, char * str2, char c){
   int length = 0;
   for (int i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        length++;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++){
      if (str1[i] == c){
         str2[i] = '*';
      }
      else {
         str2[i] = str1[i];
      }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i<= length; i++){
    printf("%c", str2[i]);
   }
}

int isPalindrome(char *str){
   int length = 0;
   for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
        length++;
   }
   int j = length - 1;
   int reversible = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
      if (str[i] != str[j]){
         reversible++;
         break;
    }
      j--;
   }
   if (reversible > 0){
    printf("\nString is not a palindrome\n");
   }
   else {
    printf("\nString is replaceable\n");
   }
}

int main(){
  removeChar(string, string2, 'm');
  isPalindrome(palindrome);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this code it says the string is not a palindrome when it should be, but why is it that if I change `isPalindrome(palindrome);` to `isPalindrome("madam");` it works.

Also Why is it that if I comment out `//removeChar(string, string2, 'm');`,  `isPalindrome()` will work properly.

Comment: The most likely answer is that `removeChar` is writing past the end of an array, and trashing the palindrome string.

Comment: Have you attempted to debug this in any way? The best way to do that is to run your program in a debugger. Or even adding more debug print statements to check the variable values and code paths. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Note: `string[]` is an array of 8 characters. `string2[]` is an array of 4 characters. In C arrays are assigned a size when they are declared. That size doesn't change when you write to the array, and nothing is watching to make sure that you stay within the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow. `removeChar` implicitly assumes that `str2` is the same length as `str1`. So when you run this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++){
      if (str1[i] == c){
         str2[i] = '*';
      }
      else {
         str2[i] = str1[i];
      }
}
```

with `str1` being `"cameron"` and `str2` being `"mah"`, you go past the boundaries of `str2` and into the memory where `palindrome` is stored. So after you run `removeChar(string, string2, 'm');`, the `char[]` that used to hold `mah\0` now holds `ca*e` and the `char[]` that used to hold `madam\0` now holds `ron\0m\0`. Obviously, `"ron"` is not a palindrome. Try printing the values of your strings after `removeChar(string, string2, 'm');` and you should see this in action.

The only reason you're allowed to do this at all without a segmentation fault is because you're using `char[]` instead of `char*`, by the way. You might prefer to use pointers over arrays so things like this don't fail silently.